# solve.QP in R doesn't give a solution satisfying the constraint

Tags: programming, statistics

I've dealing with a quadratic programming problem as following, and my objective is to get a 49*1 vector.

$$\widehat{\boldsymbol{w}}^{0}(\tau):=\underset{\boldsymbol{w}(\tau) \in \mathbb{W}}{\arg \min }\left(\hat{\boldsymbol{\psi}}^{*}(\tau)-\hat{\boldsymbol{\Psi}}^{*}(\tau) \boldsymbol{w}(\tau)\right)^{\top}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol{\psi}}^{*}(\tau)-\hat{\Psi}^{*}(\tau) \boldsymbol{w}(\tau)\right) $$

where $\mathbb{W}:=\left\{\boldsymbol{w} \mid \boldsymbol{w} \in[0,1]^{N-1} \text { and } \boldsymbol{\iota}_{N-1}^{\top} \boldsymbol{w}=1\right\}$

Thus when I use solve.QP function in R, I define
$$psi1 = \hat{\boldsymbol{\psi}}^{*}(\tau)$$
$$psi2 = \hat{\boldsymbol{\Psi}}^{*}(\tau)$$
I suppose my constraint $A^{\top}\boldsymbol{w}\geq b_{0}$ are
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&\ldots&1&1\\
1&0&0&\ldots&0&0\\
0&1&0&\ldots&0&0\\
0&0&1&\ldots&0&0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots &\vdots \\
0&0&0&\ldots&1&0\\
0&0&0&\ldots&0&1\\
-1&0&0&\ldots&0&0\\
0&-1&0&\ldots&0&0\\
0&0&-1&\ldots&0&0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots &\vdots \\
0&0&0&\ldots&-1&0\\
0&0&0&\ldots&0&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
b_{0}=(1,0,0,0,\cdots,0,0,-1,-1,-1,\cdots,-1,-1)^{\top}
$$

```
Dmat = (t(psi2)%*%psi2)/2
dvec = t(2*(t(psi1)%*%psi2))
Amat = t(rbind(rep(1,(unit-1)),diag(1,49,49),diag(-1,49,49))
bvec = c(1,rep(0,(unit-1)),rep(-1,(unit-1)))
w_hat=solve.QP(Dmat,dvec,Amat,bvec,meq=1)$solution
```

However, I get a solution like this:
[image]

Obviously there are some negative numbers in this solution and it doesn't satisfy my constraint, and I'm wondering why this happens. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show all your code.

Comment: I have edited my question and updated my code, thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what quadratic programming problem you're trying to solve (maybe formulate it mathematically)?

Comment: I have edited my question with all codes and the objective function, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please stop significantly changing the question. My answer was valid until the problem turned out to be something else entirely.

Comment: Your negative numbers are within machine precision from 0 and hence all is fine.